# Need help converting a MySQL query with a self join to SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Here's the query, I'd post my work so far, but I'm certain it's useless. The goal here is to avoid sub-queries as well, this is a situation where performance is very important.

My MySQL Query:

```
SELECT o.id FROM orders o
    JOIN cart_items ci ON (o.cart_id = ci.cart_id)
    LEFT JOIN cart_items cii ON (cii.cart_id = ci.cart_id AND cii.stage <> 'crowdfunding') 
    WHERE cii.cart_id IS null AND ci.stage = 'crowdfunding';
```

Data in pseudo-code:

```
Order {
    id: Integer(primary_key(True))
    cart_id: Integer(foreign_key(Cart.id))
}
Cart {
    id: integer(primary_key(True))
}
CartItem {
    id: integer(primary_key(True))
    cart_id: integer(foreign_key(Cart.id))
}
```

What I've got so far for my SQLAlchemy query:

```
        def get_orders_for_stage_q(stage):
            join_subq = model.Session.query(ci).\
                join(
                    cii,
                    (cii.cart_id == ci.cart_id and cii.stage != stage),
                    isouter=True
                ).\
                filter(
                    cii.cart_id == None,
                    ci.stage == stage
                ).subquery()

            q = model.Session.query(model.Order.id).\
                join(join_subq, model.Order.cart_id == join_subq.c.cart_id)

            return q
```

EDIT:
This query gives me all `orders` that have a `cart_id` that belongs to a `carts` where every `cart_items` that belongs to that `carts` item has a stage == 'crowdfunding'.

Comment: Where is `sub-query` ?

Comment: I don't have one, I have a version of this query that uses a sub-query instead of the self join, but this one is about 50% faster and the other is much too slow in SQLAlchemy. :/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Help us help you, and share some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I added more information. I don't think I can optimize that query anymore, but I also can't get a SQLAlchemy query to achieve the same effect without using a sub-query. Sub-queries are very slow in SQLAlchemy. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, verified to work in my environment. :)

```
            q = model.Session.query(model.Order.id).\
                join(
                    ci, model.Order.cart_id == ci.cart_id
                ).\
                join(
                    cii,
                    and_(
                        cii.cart_id == ci.cart_id,
                        cii.stage != stage
                    ),
                    isouter=True
                ).\
                filter(
                    cii.cart_id == None,
                    ci.stage == stage
                ).distinct()
```